GeoDjango fails to load SpatiaLite, but not Jupyter?
I am trying to use SpatiaLite for a GeoDjango application on a Windows 10 machine using Anaconda, but, when I run python manage.py dbshell, I get an error "CommandError: You appear not to have the 'spatialite' program installed or on your path."
In my GeoDjango settings.py file I have defined my paths:
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:/Users/[my name]/AppData/Local/anaconda3/envs/web/Library/bin/gdal.dll'
SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:/Users/[my name]/AppData/Local/anaconda3/envs/web/Library/bin/mod_spatialite.dll'

I have also defined my database like:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Prior to working on the GeoDjango application, I was successfully creating a SpatiaLite database using Jupyter Notebooks. Within these notebooks I was able to execute code like:
conn = sqlite3.connect(/path/to/database)
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')")

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS files''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

and
conn = sqlite3.connect(/path/to/database)
conn.enable_load_extension(True)
conn.execute("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')")

columns_list = list(gdf.columns[:-1])
columns_str = ', '.join(columns_list)
sql_string = "SELECT {}, AsText(bounds) FROM files WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND aoi_id = {}".format(columns_str, aoi_id)

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_string, conn)
df = df.rename(columns={'AsText(bounds)': 'geometry'}, errors='raise')
df['geometry'] = shapely.wkt.loads(df['geometry'])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')

conn.commit()
conn.close()

gdf.head()

Since I was able to build a table, query it, and plot the results, I think SpatiaLite is properly installed within my environment, but something is wrong with my pathing to "mod_spatialite.dll" despite this being the only copy of the file on my computer. Does anyone have any ideas?

I was able to solve this by downloading the Windows binaries (see here) and placing them in my project directory.
